# Xournal++ file extension gets associated with gzip

Tags: file-format, mime-type, gzip

I installed **xournal++** on kde plasma kubuntu 20.04(LTS) by **snap**. All went well except the file extension **.xopp** got associated with gzip.

I removed the snap version and reinstalled via **deb**. The problem remains.

How to disassociate **.xopp** with "gzip"? I could not find its entry anywhere in **.list** files.

Answer (score 0):

I renamed it to filename.gzip and then revert its name again to filename.xopp and voila the problem gets solved, but i am not sure how.